# tensorflow multiplication between 2 3d tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two tensors:

```
A.shape = (3000, 1, 5)
B.shape = (3000, 5, 259)
```

I want to get a result tensor whose shape is (3000, 1, 259).

So intuitively I am multiplying every (1, 5) matrix in A with its corresponding (5, 259) matrix in B to get 3000 (1, 259) matrices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it to work.

It is as simple as:

```
tf.matmul(A, B)
```